# biblatex with category for multiple bibliography at the end of the book, 2 problems with headings

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, fancyhdr

The following MWE reproduces 2 problems which are described at the end of it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[twoside,paperwidth=15cm,paperheight=21cm,includehead,top=11mm,bottom=19mm,outer=23mm,inner=18mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,sortlocale=auto,bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authortitle-ticomp,datecirca=true,dateera=secular]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample-base.bib}% Can be found in TexLive2023
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Introduction}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Chapter1}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Chapter2}

\addtocategory{Introduction}{Abril07}
\addtocategory{Introduction}{Cohen07}
\addtocategory{Introduction}{JCohen96}
\addtocategory{Introduction}{Kosiur01}
\addtocategory{Introduction}{Harel79}
\addtocategory{Chapter1}{Editor00}
\addtocategory{Chapter1}{Editor00a}
\addtocategory{Chapter1}{Spector90}
\addtocategory{Chapter1}{Douglass98}
\addtocategory{Chapter1}{Knuth97}
\addtocategory{Chapter1}{Knuth98}
\addtocategory{Chapter1}{VanGundy09}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{VanGundy08}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{GM05}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{Smith10}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{VanGundy07}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{Andler79}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{Harel78}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{anisi03}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{Introduction}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape Introduction}} 
\fancypagestyle{Chapter1}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape The first Chapter}} 
\fancypagestyle{Chapter2}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape The second Chapter}} 
\fancypagestyle{Afterword}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape Afterword}}    
\fancypagestyle{bibIntroduction}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape Bibliography}} 
\fancypagestyle{bibChapter1}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape Bibliography 1}} 
\fancypagestyle{bibChapter2}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape Bibliography 2}} 

\begin{document}
    
\section*{Introduction}
\pagestyle{Introduction}
\nocite{Abril07}
\nocite{Cohen07}
\nocite{JCohen96}
\nocite{Kosiur01}
\nocite{Harel79}

\clearpage
\section{Chapter 1}
\pagestyle{Chapter1}
\nocite{Editor00}
\nocite{Editor00a}
\nocite{Spector90}
\nocite{Douglass98}
\nocite{Knuth97}
\nocite{Knuth98}
\nocite{VanGundy09}
\nocite{VanGundy08}

\clearpage
\section{Chapter 2} 
\pagestyle{Chapter2}
\nocite{GM05}
\nocite{Smith10}
\nocite{VanGundy07}
\nocite{Andler79}
\nocite{Harel78}
\nocite{anisi03}


\clearpage
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\defbibheading{BibIntroduction}[Bibliography]{\chapter*{#1}\pagestyle{bibIntroduction}}
\defbibheading{BibChapter1}[Bibliography 1]{\chapter*{#1}\pagestyle{bibChapter1}}
\defbibheading{BibChapter2}[Bibliography 2]{\chapter*{#1}\pagestyle{bibChapter2}}

\printbibliography[category={Introduction},title={Bibliography},heading=BibIntroduction]
\printbibliography[category={Chapter1},title={Bib: The first Chapter},heading=BibChapter1]
\printbibliography[category={Chapter2},title={Bib: The second Chapter},heading=BibChapter2] 
\endgroup

% Two problems in output:
% 1. page 5: the heading should be empty (and not "Bibliography 1")
% 2. page 7: the heading should be "Bibliography 2" (and not "The second Chapter")

\clearpage
\section*{Afterword}
\pagestyle{Afterword}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: `INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'sample-base.bib' for section 0
ERROR - Cannot find 'sample-base.bib'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1` If it is in TL 2023, it is not where Biber can find it. `kpsewhich sample-base.bib` confirms this by returning nothing. Why not use `biblatex-examples.bib` which everyone has and the standard tools can find?

Comment: Why do you think the heading should be empty on page 5?

Comment: I wrote half an answer to this, but discovered I don't know what the question is.

Comment: Page 5 needs to be empty, since this page shows the title of chapter one for the bibliography, and this is pagestyle{empty} by standard. This is logic. In the other way it showed redundant information, a double info is not needed in this case and in my intention. The problem has somehow to do with the clearpage, since in my larger source.tex the title of other chapters for bib are correcly formatted. Only when the title of the chapter for the bib starts anew on a fresh page the heading is given, which should not appear on this page where the title of the chapter for the bib is set.

Comment: You shouldn't hard-code titles into your page style definitions or put `\pagestyle` into `\defbibheading`. See `fancyhdr` documentation. As far as I can see, you're getting exactly the results you've asked for, given how you've set up headers and footers.

Comment: In my larger source.tex I have 10 chapters for bib. And they give the result I need and want, except what I have described in the comment above and what is shown in the MWE. I do not know why these problems are happening and not behaving as like for the other bib chapters. How else should I set the headings? I have no idea - and thought the code in the MWE would work for the intention. How else should I set the headings?

Comment: As I said above, see the `fancyhdr` documentation. You probably want to look at the sections on LaTeX's 'marks'. You want your headings set using the marks mechanism both for reasons of flexibility and because you're more liable to get the wrong headings on pages otherwise. And don't put the page style in the heading definition ....

Comment: Sorry, but fancyhdr does not help. And if I delete the pagestyle in defbibheading it makes the situation more worse and far more away from intention.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot run the example and the actual question is a bit tricky to figure out what with it being only commented into the document body and not the text body of the question. Is this question still relevant in light of your self-answered question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/702292/35864? If so, could you please update it to include a compilable example (like the one in your other question), remove any references to the other problem you have already resolved and mention what needs to be changed more explicitly in the question.

Comment: Indeed this unanswered question here is now irrelevant and does not need to survive here. I suggest to delete it, since the main problem is answered in this other question raised two days after this question here. It would be a doubled question and answer of the same problem raised by the same person. I think deletion has to be done.

Comment: You should be able to delete your own question. Community moderation can usually not delete a question. It can only be closed. In this case I think the best I could do was to vote to close.