# \defbibheading does not do its job when using category and \addtocategory for multible bib at the end of a book with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, header-footer

With the following MWE a problem arises which is described below: the heading of the bib chapters are not showing the proper text which is defined by `\defbibheading`. I have no idea why not. Thank you for support.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[twoside,paperwidth=15cm,paperheight=21cm,includehead,top=11mm,bottom=19mm,outer=23mm,inner=18mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,sortlocale=auto,bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authortitle-ticomp,datecirca=true,dateera=secular]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Introduction}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Chapter1}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Chapter2}
\defbibheading{BibIntroduction}[Bibliography]{\chapter*{#1}}
\defbibheading{BibChapter1}[Bibliography 1]{\chapter*{#1}}
\defbibheading{BibChapter2}[Bibliography 2]{\chapter*{#1}}

\addtocategory{Introduction}{aksin}
\addtocategory{Introduction}{angenendt}
\addtocategory{Introduction}{baez/article}
\addtocategory{Introduction}{bertram}
\addtocategory{Introduction}{dooky}
\addtocategory{Chapter1}{matuz:doody}
\addtocategory{Chapter1}{gillies}
\addtocategory{Chapter1}{glashow}
\addtocategory{Chapter1}{herrmann}
\addtocategory{Chapter1}{kastenholz}
\addtocategory{Chapter1}{murray}
\addtocategory{Chapter1}{reese}
\addtocategory{Chapter1}{sarfraz}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{shore}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{sigfridsson}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{spiegelberg}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{springer}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{weinberg}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{artistotle:anima}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{aristotle:physics}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{aristotle:poetics}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{aristotle:rhetoric}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{augustine}
\addtocategory{Chapter2}{averroes/bland}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{Introduction}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape Introduction}} 
\fancypagestyle{Chapter1}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape The first Chapter}} 
\fancypagestyle{Chapter2}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape The second Chapter}} 
\fancypagestyle{Afterword}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape Afterword}}    
\fancypagestyle{bibIntroduction}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape Bibliography}} 
\fancypagestyle{bibChapter1}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape Bibliography 1}} 
\fancypagestyle{bibChapter2}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape Bibliography 2}} 

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}
\pagestyle{Introduction}
\nocite{aksin}
\nocite{angenendt}
\nocite{baez/article}
\nocite{bertram}
\nocite{doody}


\clearpage

\section{Chapter 1}
\pagestyle{Chapter1}
\nocite{matuz:doody}
\nocite{gillies}
\nocite{glashow}
\nocite{herrmann}
\nocite{kastenholz}
\nocite{murray}
\nocite{reese}
\nocite{sarfraz}

\clearpage
\section{Chapter 2} 
\pagestyle{Chapter2}
\nocite{shore}
\nocite{sigfridsson}
\nocite{spiegelberg}
\nocite{springer}
\nocite{weinberg}
\nocite{aristotle:anima}
\nocite{aristotle:physics}
\nocite{aristotle:poetics}
\nocite{aristotle:rhetoric}
\nocite{augustine}
\nocite{averroes/bland}

\clearpage

\printbibliography[heading=BibIntroduction,category={Introduction},title={Bibliography}]
\printbibliography[heading=BibChapter1,category={Chapter1},title={Bib: The first Chapter}]
\printbibliography[heading=BibChapter2,category={Chapter2},title={Bib: The second Chapter}] 

% Problem in Output:
% page 6 and 8: the heading should be "Bibliography 2" (and not "The second Chapter")
% What needs to be done with defbibheading ?

\clearpage
\section*{Afterword}
\pagestyle{Afterword}   

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer for myself. I just put in `\clearpage\pagestyle{bibChapterX}` in the following way:

```
...
\clearpage
\pagestyle{bibIntroduction}
\defbibheading{BibIntroduction}{\chapter*{#1}}
\printbibliography[heading=BibIntroduction,category={Introduction},title={Bibliography}]

\clearpage
\pagestyle{bibChapter1}
\defbibheading{BibChapter1}{\chapter*{#1}}
\printbibliography[heading=BibChapter1,category={Chapter1},title={Bib: The first Chapter}]

\clearpage
\pagestlye{bibChapter2}
\defbibheading{BibChapter2}{\chapter*{#1}}
\printbibliography[heading=BibChapter2,category={Chapter2},title={Bib: The second Chapter}] 
...
```

Additionally I found out that heading is different from pagestyle when using it with biblatex. This was my confusion and hindrance to understand what to do.

As a variation, instead of printing the whole bibliography chapterwise at the end of the book, printing it chapterwise at the end of the according chapter:

```
\chapter{This is Chapter X}
....
\clearpage
\pagestyle{bibChapterX}% defined with the help of the fancyhdr package, see above
\defbibheading{BibChapterX}[Bibliography X]{\chapter*{#1}}
\printbibliography[heading=BibChapterX,title={Bib: The chapter X},category={ChapterX}]

\clearpage
\chapter{This is Chapter Y}
...
```